# What is the Java annotation in Hibernate used to auto increment a MySQL Primary Key - @Id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, identifier

In this code I need the id to be the primary key and also it must be incremented.
is getter and setter required for id ?

```
@Entity
public class Contact {
@Id
private Integer id;
private String firstName;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

Comment: did you try to search for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although you could use `GenerationType.AUTO`, it's not a very good idea for MySQL and Hibernate 5 because it will default to the `TABLE` generator which is bad for performance.

So, although [it will disable JDBC batch inserts][3], you should use `IDENTITY`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

or you can use `native` identifier generator which falls back to `IDENTITY` on MySQL:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, 
    generator="native"
)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "native", 
    strategy = "native"
)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 4):

try to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

take a look in this doc about [Auto Generated Values](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated)